# Javascript and D3 error: Cannot read property 'cloud' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, runtime-error

I am having an issue creating a word cloud using JavaScript and D3. An error is popping up saying "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloud' of undefined".

I am not familiar enough with JS to be able to understand how to fix this (I am only using JS because this is a class assignment). I would appreciate some guidance on the matter.

Essentially, I want to take the name of each entry in my CSV file and write the name in the word cloud based on one of the numerical entries. Some of those entries are negative though, so those I have set to equal 1pt font.
Below, I have attached the function code that should be creating the word cloud. After failing to get it to work, I looked up a tutorial and this code is almost the same as the tutorial I found, so I do not understand why it won't work.

I am using D3 version 5

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And this is the library that the tutorial suggested using:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
```

```
//define margins
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 100, left: 100},
width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 760 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// add the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("/data/a1-mutualFunds.csv", function(data){

  // Constructs a new cloud layout instance
  var designLayout = d3.layout.cloud()
    .size([width, height])
    .words(data.map(function(d) { return {text: d.Name, size:d.ytd}; }))
    .padding(5)        //space between words
    .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .fontSize(function(d) { 
      if(d.ytd<0){return 1;}
      return d.ytd; })      // font size of words
    .on("end", draw);
  designLayout.start();

  // Draw the words
  function draw(words) {
    svg
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + designLayout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + designLayout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
        .selectAll("text")
          .data(words)
        .enter().append("text")
          .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.ytd; })
          .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-family", "Impact")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
          })
          .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
})
```

Comment: I actually can't get 3 of my 5 tables working, but I am focusing on this one at the moment (^_^')

Comment: The error is stating that `d3.layout` is undefined. I'm not familiar with d3 so I can't help you further, but that's probably where you should start looking.

Comment: Please indicate which version of D3 you are using, and which library you are using for the cloud (word clouds are not part of plain D3.js but use a separate library/plug in).

Comment: Just added that to the description. Thanks for pointing out that I hadn't given that info!

Comment: What happens if you call d3.cloud instead of d3.layout.cloud ? Before d3 version 4 the d3 modules were organized differently. Since v4 all modules and plugins are called as d3.x with no nesting

Comment: It will say that d3.cloud is not a function @ee2Dve

Answer (score 2):

As stated in previous answers the reason is the new versions of d3 which work differently with modules.

I got it working with d3 v6 by importing and using d3-cloud directly

```
import * as cloud from 'd3-cloud';


var designLayout = cloud()
```

instead of

```
var designLayout = d3.layout.cloud()
```